# How can i run java application with console-only?

Tags: java, linux, terminal

I wrote an application in java that have graphical window. (and uses open-gl)
Now, this application should work on Linux servers.
What happends if i try to run the application on a linux terminal-only operation system?
I Don't care if the application won't show the graphical window.
Is it possible to run a graphical linux application with console only?

Comment: Search for "headless java" - it turned up some results I didn't even know about so I entirely retracted my earlier comment! - now, will said program still be *useful*? Well, .. TIAS and YMMV. If the program only supports GUI IO it will generally be of minimal/no use as a CLI. However, in general, it is not possible to run a program that requires X without *an* X display to connect to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I believe it should. In my experience: Once the program starts to run, it does what it was programmed to do. The Java program doesn't care if the user can see or interact with it.

Comment: Thanks, i hope it is true.

Answer (score 0):

Surround your program with:

```
try { 
// your code here
} catch (java.awt.HeadlessException e) {
// your console code here
}
```

The way this works is that the JVM will throw a catchable HeadlessException if there's no GUI display, so you know you're on a command line, else it will display the GUI.

Comment: then, the last answer is incorrect? because it'll throw exception.